# StackView contains - не работает

Tags: qt, qt5, pyqt5, qml, pyqt

Мне нужно проверить, находиться ли конкретный объект сейчас в stackview, пробую получить это методом contains

```
stack.contains(mainc1);
```

но получаю ошибку

> "Could not convert argument 0 at"
>        "expression for enabled@qrc:/main.qml:21"
>   "Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is dangerous and deprecated."
>   "This will throw a JavaScript TypeError in future releases of Qt!"

И не понимаю что делать, почему сообственно выходит такая ошибка?

mainc1

```
Component {
    id: mainc1;
    Rectangle {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @Kromster вы наверное никогда не использовали qml. По вопросу видно, что метод contains не работает верным образок, т.е. выдает ошибку, в ней и проблема, ведь я не могу проверить находиться ли объект в стеке или нет.

Comment: а mainc1 как определён

Comment: @magrif это простой id, компонента, обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете неверную функцию, гляньте документацию для `StackView`. Используйте `find`:

```
Component {
    id: comp1
    Item {
        property bool ok: false
    }
}

Component {
    id: comp2
    Item {
        property bool ok: true
    }
}

StackView {
    id: stack
    Component.onCompleted: {
        stack.push(comp1)
        stack.push(comp2)
        var item = stack.find(function(item, index){
            return item.ok == true
        })
        if(item != undefined) {
            console.log("catch it!")
        }
    }
}
```